# Отправка изображения в Telegrambot в виде byte []

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть массив байт описывающий ч-б изображение (qr-код):

```
Byte[] byteCodes
```

Как можно отправить изображение из данного байт-кода в телеграм-бот?

Нашел примеры как можно отправить изображение из директории по ссылке, но мне это не подходит у меня в виде байт-кода.

Попробовал преобразовать байт-код в объект Image следующим образом:

```
public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
```

А потом передать его через:

```
await _telegramBotClient.SendPhotoAsync(message.Chat.Id, QRcodeServices.byteArrayToImage(byteCodes));
```

Но мне выдает ошибку, что метод SendPhotoAsync принимает другой параметр - `InputOnLineFile`

Comment: Попробуйте вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion/24315437. Сначала сделайте из вашего массива байтов изображение, а затем отправьте по API телеграма

Comment: @AlAvenger, попробовал так сделать, но метод передачи изображения пишет, что он ожидает другой параметр - в вопросе описал

Comment: Полагаю, метод SendPhotoAsync требует объект Bitmap, а не Image. Попробуйте сконвертировать Image в Bitmap - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383256/how-can-i-convert-a-jpg-file-into-a-bitmap-using-c/24383391

Comment: @AlAvenger, Bitmap тоже не хочет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputOnlineFile` может отправлять только готовый файл изображения. Не `Image`, не `Bitmap`.

```
// Bitmap bmp = ...
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    ms.Position = 0;
    await _telegramBotClient.SendPhotoAsync(message.Chat.Id, new InputOnLineFile(ms, "image.png"));
}
```

То есть отправляется именно сохраненная в формате изображения картинка, а не что-либо другое.

Если файл в формате png у вас уже в массиве байт, то код будет немного проще.

```
// byte[] bytes = ...
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    await _telegramBotClient.SendPhotoAsync(message.Chat.Id, new InputOnLineFile(ms, "image.png"));
}
```

Есть и другой конструктор у `InputOnLineFile` на случай если файл например уже загружен в сети.

```
new InputOnLineFile("https://site.ru/image.png");
```

Вместо png может быть jpg или другой формат изображения.